# Nested json parsing in ajax call

Tags: json

I have many fields in my gsp.

I am catching those field values by their ID in javascript.

I want to pass those values as nested json to one method in my controller.

Can anyone please help me in passing those field values and field names as value and key pair aka in json format.It should nested json format.

If anyone can give a small example,so that it would be helpful.

e.g.  key:[field1value:{field2name:field2value,field3name:field3value}]

field names would be hardcoded and field values would be coming from form submit.

Thanks.

Comment: Step 1. Build the data structure you want. Step 2. Use the functionality in your programming language of choice to serialize that data structure to JSON.

Comment: here you can find samples http://www.json.com/#examples

Comment: Thanks.guys.I got the answer.For a nested json,for each value,I had to do key:JSON.Stringify(value).After that I was able to pass that value.